# Storing const reference to an object in class

Tags: c++, c++11, pass-by-reference

This sounds like a basic question, but I didn't find any comprehensive answer, so here it is. Consider this code snippet:

```
struct A {
    const std::string& s;
    A(const std::string& s) : s(s) {}
};

int main() {
    A a("abc");
    std::cout << a.s << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/v2J53u).

As long as I understand, this is UB. String literal "abc" binds to `const std::string&` in constructor, creating a temporary string object. It is also bound to reference `a.s`, and it is destroyed once `a` is constructed. That is, const reference cannot chain lifetime prolongation. Dangling reference, boom. In this particular case I see no output at all on ideone.com, but anything could happen (remember [velociraptors](https://xkcd.com/292/)).

Ok, this one is clear. But what if this is actually our very intent: we want to store a const reference to an object? To an existing one, not to temporary? This sounds like a very natural task, yet I came up with only one (almost) natural solution to it. Accepting constructor's argument by `std::reference_wrapper` instead of by reference:

```
    A(std::reference_wrapper<const std::string> r) : s(r) {}
```

Since `std::reference_wrapper` has deleted constructors from temporaries:

```
reference_wrapper( T&& x ) = delete;
```

this works just like expected. However, this is not quite elegant. Another approach I can think of is to accept forwarding reference `T&&` and to reject everything except const l-value strings with `std::enable_if`. This is even less elegant, I think.

Any other approaches?

**UPD** Another question: is this a legitimate usage of `std::reference_wrapper`, or may it be considered too specific?

Comment: Any reason why `A` cannot just have a regular `std::string`? `A::s` is likely to dangle even if it receives an lvalue and the reference breaks the assignment operator. Does this have a use case or is it purely academic?

Comment: `A(const std::string &&) = delete;` might do what you want. I still don't think it is a good idea.

Comment: @nwp This might be useful in utility classes, where we control lifetime of its instances and may guarantee they will not outlive passed object. I used `std::string` to denote an expensive to copy object. An alternative, safer, solution would be to store `shared_ptr` on this object. However, this might be an overkill in simple scenarios.

Comment: @nwp a use case that stands out to me is a no-copy string view.

Comment: I think your solution is pretty nice actually.  If you want to make it read a bit better, you might use an alias template for std::reference_wrapper.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd say the natural solution would be to do what `reference_wrapper` does: prevent construction from temporaries:

```
struct A {
    const std::string& s;
    A(const std::string& s) : s(s) {}
    A(std::string&&) = delete;
};
```

You should also bear in mind that having a data member of reference type makes the class non-assignable (not even move assignment is possible) by default, and it's generally difficult to implement an assignment operator. You should consider storing a pointer instead of a reference:

```
struct A {
    const std::string* s;
    A(const std::string& s) : s(&s) {}
    A(std::string&&) = delete;
};
```

Comment: Good answer. The one downside is that if we have multiple such arguments, it would be quite difficult to `delete` all unwanted flavors.

Comment: I don't like pointer approach - it has no syntactic information that it cannot be nullptr.

Comment: @Mikhail I consider an imperfect, but usable object superioir to a pure, but unusable one ;-) Still, you could use something like `not_null<T>` from the [Core Guideline library](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md)

Comment: Yes, also thought about `not_null` here.

Answer (score 1):

There is a very simple class [`lvalue_ref`](https://github.com/akrzemi1/explicit#tool-lvalue_ref) provided in the lightweight and convenient ["explicit"](https://github.com/akrzemi1/explicit) library by Andrzej Krzemieński, which solves exactly this problem with a clear intention:

```
struct Processor
{
  Big const& _big;
  explicit Processor(lvalue_ref<const Big> b) : _big(b) {}
};

const Big b {};
Processor p {b}; // ok
Processor q {Big{}}; // error (temporary)
```